# Multiple post xml data in guzzle and multiple async request

Tags: php, symfony, curl, timeout, guzzle6

How can I create an asynchronous request to multiple URI with different post data for each?

I am able to get the data for each of the URI, but I want to make it asynchronous.

Also, how do I timeout if the request takes too long?

My code:

```
//url
$ur1 = 'www.exaample1.com';
$ur2 = 'www.Test.com';
//xml
$ur1_xml = ''; // xml code
$ur2_xml = ''; // xml code
//headers
$ur1_header = array("POST  HTTP/1.1",
        "Content-type: application/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($ur1_xml));
$ur2_header = array("POST  HTTP/1.1",
        "Content-type: application/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($ur2_xml));

       $client = new Client();

    // make request

    $request = new Request('POST', $ur1_url, $ur1_headers,$ur1_xml);
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(simplexml_load_string($response->getBody()));
        echo '</pre>';
    });

 die();
```

Answer (score 1):

For `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` send Async requests you can get benefit from Guzzle promises. Headers and POST fields should go into an array as [documents state](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
.
.
.
$client = new Client();
$promises = [
    $client->postAsync($url1, ['headers' => $headers1, 'form_params' => $postData1]),
    $client->postAsync($url2, ['headers' => $headers2, 'form_params' => $postData2]),
    $client->postAsync($url3, ['headers' => $headers3, 'form_params' => $postData3])
];

$results = Promise\unwrap($promises);
$results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();

// response headers of first request
print_r($results[0]['value']->getHeaders()); 

// retrieved contents of second request
echo $results[1]['value']->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: I tried with the above code before but i get  ` Error: Call to a member function getHeaders() on a non-object `

Comment: also its 'body' and not 'form_params'

Comment: `form_params` is the right way to attach POST fields to a request as per [Guzzle's doc](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields). But I updated my answer due to the error you got on `getHeaders()`. Please check @PeterHahn

Comment: 2 things: 1. $postData should have `body` index. 2. I think this is only HTTP Post for application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have 3 RestAPI and 4 SOAP API some require application/xml, application/json, application/text.  I get Client Error 415 i.e unsupported media format

Comment: I have successfully implemented using curl_multi but the code is very long about 200 lines though i have separated body, header for each ApI's and then curl multi handling making it very long.  A quick google search suggested **Guzzle**

Comment: My answer tries to show you how async requests can be done properly with Guzzle. If you need to POST your field as `application/json` then you can add this key/value pair `'Content-type' => 'application/json'` to `headers` key's array and avoid using `form_params` on the other hand or simply use [`json`](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=request#json). Sending other types can be done by the first same approach. @PeterHahn